# Webpage Scraping

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I'm trying to get the tracking result for a lots of numbers from www.ups.com
So far, I was able to get the result perfectly fine by exceuting the VBA using F8.
However, it gives me an runtime error while using F5 to run the code for the complete set.

I would like to know the date and where the package is left.

Reference Tracking number

```
1Z5X10F70364459911
1Z5X10F79065556123
1Z5X10F70364649537
1Z5X10F79064044142
1Z5X10F70365323958
1Z5X10F79066952961
1Z5X10F70364875177
1Z5X10F79065114583
1Z5X10F70366375196
```

Here is my code:

```
Sub Test2()
Dim Tnx As String
Dim lastrow As Integer
Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
Dim data As String
Dim Doc As HTMLDocument

'For selection last row with count
lastrow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

IE.Visible = False
IE.navigate "www.ups.com"

Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Loop

For i = 2 To lastrow
    Tnx = Sheet1.Cells(i, 3).Value

    IE.document.getElementById("ups-track--qs").Value = Tnx
    IE.document.getElementById("ups-tracking-submit").Click

    Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Loop
    Set Doc = IE.document

    data = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("ups-form_label")(1).innerText
    Sheet1.Cells(i, 4).Value = data

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: At which line does the runtime error occur, and what is the error? Also, is the error on the first iteration, or does it happen also at later iterations?

Comment: Error accors at data = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("ups-form_label")(1).innerText     and it occurs at 1st iteration and gives a runtime error 91

Comment: Hey maybe I'm missing something I don''t know, I'm new to VBA and all i want with this project is to track some packages automatically using VBA

Comment: Are you sure there is an element with this class name? Because when I open the web page in the browser, and enter `document.getElementsByClassName("ups-form_label").length` I get back `0`.

Comment: Yes there is, Please use the reference tracking number in the website and inspect the element where it says as Delivered on or left at

Comment: (I had gotten to the country selection page, which is why I couldn't find the element.) My guess is that parts of the page are loaded via Javascript, and even though the page reports as complete, the Javascript is still loading. I would suggest some kind of delay, perhaps using `setTimeout` or using the Windows kernel Sleep function.

Comment: Can you please edit mycode since I dont know how to use the windows kernel sleep function? please and I'm from India

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to follow the instructions on the site.  You're using the wrong URL for your country:

```
https://www.ups.com/WebTracking/track?loc=en_IN
```

Secondly, if "all i want with this project is to track some packages automatically" then why not just do it the same way that everyone else does?

The site is made for tracking multiple packages and automatically sending you updates, etc.  It's UPS, that's what they do.

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

With no knowledge of VBA this is not a good starter project, and this site is not a place for teaching beginners the basics of coding.  Please see the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
Do Until data <> ""
    On Error Resume Next
    data = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("ups-form_label")(1).innerText
    On Error GoTo 0
    DoEvents
Loop
Sheet1.Cells(i, 4).Value = data
```

Answer (score 0):

So this is bit hacky but work.

**1) Parsing the HTML**

```
Option Explicit

Sub ExtractDeliveryDetails()

    Dim Tnx As String, lastrow As Long, i As Long, ie As New InternetExplorer

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

        ie.Visible = True
        ie.navigate "www.ups.com"

        Do While ie.Busy = True Or ie.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

        For i = 2 To lastrow
            Tnx = .Cells(i, 3).Value
            ie.document.getElementById("ups-track--qs").Value = Tnx
            ie.document.getElementById("ups-tracking-submit").Click

            Do While ie.Busy = True Or ie.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
            Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 3)
            ie.document.getElementById("trackNums").Value = Tnx

            Dim buttons As Object
            Set buttons = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("button")

            Dim btn As Object
            For Each btn In buttons
                If InStr(btn.Value, "Track") > 0 Then
                    btn.Click
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next btn

            Do While ie.Busy = True Or ie.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
            Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 2) '<==alter timings or loop until a value can be set

            Dim htmlArray() As String
            htmlArray = Split(ie.document.body.innerHTML, "ups-form_label")

            .Cells(i, 4) = Trim$(Replace$(Replace$(Split(Replace(Split(htmlArray(1), "<p>")(1), "&nbsp;", vbNullString), "</p>")(0), Chr(10), vbNullString), vbTab, " "))
            .Cells(i, 5) = Trim$(Replace$(Replace$(Split(Replace(Split(htmlArray(2), "<p>")(1), "&nbsp;", vbNullString), "</p>")(0), Chr(10), vbNullString), vbTab, " "))

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

**2) Using querySelectorAll to match CSS**

You could also uses `querySelectorAll` at the end, instead of parsing the HTML, as follows:

```
Dim b As Object 'DispStaticNodeList
Set b = ie.document.querySelectorAll(".ups-form_label ~ p")

Dim dropDate As String, dropLocation As String

dropDate = b.item(0).innerText
dropLocation = b.item(1).innerText
.Cells(i, 4) = dropDate
.Cells(i, 5) = dropLocation
```

This has the potential to be more robust as you could loop the length of NodeList, using b.Length, testing contents for desired properties.

**Note:**

You could better re-write the `Waits` to be `Loop Until` object (e.g.  `ie.document.getElementById("trackNums")` is set, i.e. in view, with a specified timeout to prevent potential for never ending loop.

**Example output:**

[image: Output row 1]

**Interesting NodeList reference:**

1. [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)